# Performance implications of fragmented memory

Tags: pointers, optimization, caching, heap-memory

So i'm working in a context where I don't own most of the data i work with, and am usually given ref-counted pointers.

I usually try to avoid fragmented heap allocations like this, but this means I don't have a great understanding of how much of a performance hit this model will be

So, i understand that the two main drawbacks of fragmented data are prefetching and locality, but i wonder about the following scenario:

Say i have a struct that occupies about 64 bytes, which happens to be the width of a cache line on my target system.
Say also that once i get this piece of data, i work on it relatively frequently -- maybe iterating over a list of pointers to similar data 60 or so times per second

Would I expect relatively little cost from having these data being fragmented, since they're about the size of the cache line anyway, and they're accessed frequently enough that they might still be cached?

I might have a flawed understanding of cache pre-fetching, though, as I understood it to be fetching from system memory before data is required, but i realize there might be a cost associated with fetching cached data as well, especially when things are only in L2 or L3

I don't really know how frequently cached items are flushed, or how the cpu decides what to flush and when, so I suppose a follow-up question is how long would you expect the data behind a heap pointer like this persist?

Comment: The overhead is dependent of many factors. On critical factor is data alignement : if the cache lines are all aligned to X, X is big and a divisor of the cache size, then you will certainly get a *conflict miss* . The cache associativity of most cache is only 4-16 (typically 8). For example, having pointers aligned to 1 page of 4KiB with X=4096, size(L1)=32768, associativity(L1)=8 cause such an issue. The L2 will typically not help much so cache lines will be fetched from the L3. The way the L3 will react is very dependent of the target CPU microarchitecture.

Comment: If you can design your application to ensure the target data is allocated in a pool that is not bigger than the cache, then it is safe to assume data will be kept in the cache (i.e. no conflict miss and no capacity miss) assuming the application do not load/store too many cache lines during the operation. Note though that things like context switches cause deferred misses typically due to TLB flushes so you need to avoid having too many of them.

Comment: *"how frequently cached items are flushed, or how the cpu decides what to flush and when"* This is highly dependent of the target CPU architecture, the target OS, the application running, etc. It is basically impossible to answer this in general.

Comment: *"how long would you expect the data behind a heap pointer like this persist?"* As long as your application thread stay scheduled, does not move to another core, does not load too much data in the cache that could cause misses (possibly conflict misses, or even TLB ones), then it is fine. But in practice, it is hard to be sure of this...

Comment: If you have no control on the target addresses or the target platform, then the best you can do is to prefetch the cache lines before accessing them. However, be aware that software prefetching is brittle (and rather dependent of the target architecture) : too early prefetches are useless (due to the eviction of the prefetched cache lines) as well as too late ones (the CPU will stall anyway).